# How to output email information from '@' symbol and further, regardless of the length of the record

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Hello everybody.** I have some problem and therefore I ask for your help.

I need the output of the email address in the following form. Email's are stored in the database like: `example@gmail.com`, and after my request it should be like this: `@gmail.com`. Shortly, I need to display everything after the '@' symbol. The length of letters and symbols after '@' can be different.

I tried to solve the problem through `TRIM` or `SUBSTRING`, but I failed (maybe I didn’t fully understand how to do this correctly).

Query example:

```
SELECT trcc.email
FROM fregat.t_ref_catalog_contact AS trcc
WHERE email IS NOT NULL
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `concat()` and `split_part()` functions together :

```
select concat('@',split_part(email, '@', 2)) as "Result String"
  from t_ref_catalog_contact
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=139fea8d53bbc84ab0853793a96a32a9)</kbd>